# How do I add Additional element?

Tags: search, search-scope

People Search - Search Options - pick list >>

Is there a way to make "GlobalAccount" and "SalesRegion" to be Pick List in the people search's search option? Both of this fields are showing as input text box type (under search option of people search). So at least the mapping piece is done. Just need to make it drop down (aka pick list) but how? http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/687/searchextending.png

Answer (score 1):

UserProfiles properties in sharepoint are restricted to a number of data types (and accompanying control: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260784/is-it-possible-to-use-custom-data-types-for-moss-user-profile-properties), To get your field to render as a dopdown would probably involve either jquery, a control redirection using the compat.browser file (asp.net adapter design pattern) or probably a combination of the 2. Most OOTB multivalued properties will implement some sort of type ahead functionality for displaying existing values however.